# Scale a Gtkmm widget in vertically and horizontally

Tags: c++, gtk

I am trying to make a [Gtkmm::Entry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Entry.html) bigger both vertically and horizontally so that in the end it would match the shape of a square. I wasn't able to find any documentation on this and would really appreciate if someone could help.

I have seen that it is possible to use the [set size request](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5e95431f630a226b0b7297e4815ee945) method to give it a square shape however it is too small and the text written in it is illegible. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html) which supports resizing. TextEntries are typically not re-sizable.